# Loop for with big numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program to check a list of numbers, and print the first prime number of each number.
For example, if the first is `25`, it should print `23` because `25` and `24` aren't prime numbers. Everything works fine until the numbers get bigger, how can I solve it?

Current number list:

```
25 |
2017 |
4275912996 |
9223372036854770000 -> here stops working |
18446744073709500000
```

[image: list number]

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeNumber {



public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


        int numLinies=6;    // aquest es el valor que anirem modificant en els
        boolean acabat = false;
        boolean noTrobat = false;
        long x;

        // diferents jocs de proves. Recorda que sempre ha de ser vÃ lid
        String[] linies=llegirLiniesFitxer(numLinies);
        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(linies[3]);

        for (int i=0; i<linies.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(linies[i]);
        }


        while(!acabat) {
            for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
                x = Long.parseLong(linies[i]);

                System.out.println("Valor de X: " + x);
                noTrobat = false;

                while(noTrobat == false) {
                    if(esPrimo(x)) {

                        System.out.println("El numero " + x + " es el primo mes gran");
                        noTrobat = true;
                    } else {
                        x = x - 1;

                        noTrobat = false;
                    }
                }
                acabat = true;
            }
        }

    }

    private static String[] llegirLiniesFitxer(int numLin) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String[] result;
        if (numLin<0) numLin=0;
        result=new String[numLin];
        Scanner f=new Scanner(new File("Valors.csv"));
        for (int i=0; i<numLin; i++) {
            result[i]=f.nextLine();

        }
        f.close();
        return result;
    }

    private static boolean esPrimo(long n) {
        int divisiones = 0;


        for(long i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if(n%i==0) {
                divisiones++;
            }
        }

        if(divisiones == 2) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Are you able to process the no. `9223372036854770000`, does the problem occur in the no. after this? Also, pls share error message or stacktrace, if any.

Comment: Hello, no error stacktrace, just solved it using a better conditions for the check if its or not prime.

Comment: It looks like you were flirting with `BigInteger` a bit but it never came to anything.  However, should ever want to handle numbers bigger than the largest ones you're already playing with,  you _will_ need to switch to `BigInteger`s: 9223372036854770000 is _very close_ to the largest possible `'long`.